# How does the Simple XML library actually create and populate objects?

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework

I am experimenting with the [Simple XML framework](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) to process XML files on Android.
However, what's *really* starting to puzzle me is, how this library actually creates and populates the objects during XML parsing/deserialization. 
For test purposes I have declared a specific class' constructor as well as all attributes as private, so it should be impossible for any other class to create such an object nor should it be able to populate its fields. Only the provided setter methods are public.

But Simple XML somehow manages to not only create but also to populate these objects and completely ignores the setter methods!

This is a pity, because some of the setter methods were supposed to have some side effect (namely registering the object in a hash-table keyed by the passed-in value for later quicker lookup by value). But without the setter method being called that approach of course doesn't fly.

So, how does SimpleXML manage to bypass this?

Comment: My first guess is it's using reflection to get the fields and change them, bypassing access permissions.

Comment: I always thought, that also reflection obeys the access permissions. Not so? If not that would mean that Java's access protection is completely worthless...

Comment: Oh - my goodness! I googled on and one can indeed change the access to private members using AccessibleObject.setAccessible(true). This only triggers a SecurityException in the java SecurityManager prevents this. Apparently it does NOT do that - at least not by default! Deeply disappointed by Java... :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple uses reflections to to read / write objects. Hoewever, you can customize it's operations.

You can try [`@Default(DefaultType.PROPERTY)`](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/Default.html) annotation on your class, this will use the naming conventions of java beans.

If everything fails, you always can implement the (de-)serialization by your own, using a [`Converter`](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#converters).

Please check those links:

- [Overriding an annotated type](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#override)
- [Java Bean serialization](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#javabean)
- [Default object serialization](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#default)
- [Receiving persister callbacks](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#callback)

Comment: Hi - thanks for the hint! The Bean serialization is very elegant, indeed. Hadn't realized, one could also annotate setters & getters and not just variables. I think that will solve my problem. 
However, the fact that Simple overrides Java's access protection still disappoints and concerns me. If it did so controlled by an explicit flag, then so be it, but silently and by default - that's IMHO not so good or "clean"!

Comment: In most cases the way how simple handles serialization / deserialization is good; rember: You want map objects to files (or whatever) - without much effort and lines of code. There's also the possibility to customize everything of simple's progress, while it remains easy to use at all. But please report back if you where able to solve your problem. It's an interesting topic (+1 for the question btw.).

Comment: Yes, I was able to solve my problem with this approach! It very cleanly first calls the getter and then later the setter method. This is especially important for lists, as it allows to create and return arbitrary list implemenations (e.g. if the list is still null I am creating and returning a "PrettyPrintingList"-object), which nicely prints each entry onto a new line, allowing me to easier read the generated result and spot errors.
Just out of curiosity: apparently one has to annotation both, the setters AND the getters. What happens if the options (like "required") have different values?

Comment: Great!! :-) The attribute `required` sets whether the annotated field is optional or not. If set to `false` it's allowed to be missing or empty in the xml.

Comment: Btw. if your question is answered, please *accept* the answer, so it's marked as solved, thanks.

Comment: "The attribute required sets ..." I am aware of what the attribute signals. My answer aimed at the fact that with the bean serialization I am now always annotating TWO methods (setter and getter) instead of just a SINGLE field. What happens if the attributes for the two differ (say, getter has: required=true, setter has: required=false)? Or if one of them is absent? Will Simple then throw an error or silently use direct field access again for the missing read/write operation?

Comment: I'm afraid i don't know ... If the two differ, the getter-setting will be used for deserialization and the one of the setter for serialization i guess.